# What is the difference between <uniq> in BASH and <unique> in R?

Tags: r, bash, count, unique, uniq

I get different results with uniq in BASH compare to unique in R. My df look like (more than 9 thousand rows):

```
samples read_seq
ccd_x29 GCATTGGT
ccd_x29 GCATTGGT
ccd_x29 GCATTGGT
ccd_x20 GCCCGGCTAG
ccd_x19 GCATTGGTGGTT
ccd_x19 GCATTGGTGGTT
```

After bash `uniq` I get 8811 rows and with `df <- unique(df)` i get 8803 rows.

What is causing this?

Comment: For the example showed, can you show the output from BASH

Comment: Run a diff on the output to see what differs between the two.

Comment: @akrun I just perform``` cat df | uniq | wc -l``` to get the number of rows after bein uniq. And when I do ```unique``` with R the number of rows are slightly different.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with the example you showed `nrow(unique(df1))#
[1] 4` in `R` and using bash `cat tmp_today.txt | uniq | wc -l#
       4`

Comment: @Apex Please post an example that shows the difference

Comment: @akrun for a reproducible example I need to add my actual files because I don't know what is the exact problem.  based on Omair's answer, these two uniq commands are not functioning exactly in the same way. What could be a solution for ```unique``` command in R?

Comment: @Apex Not clear what you expected.  If you want a `rle` based output you can do `df %>% group_by(grp = rleid(samples, read_seq)) %>% slice(1) %>% ungroup %>% select(-grp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are interested in omitting only the previous repeated element, an option is `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(new = rleid(samples, read_seq)) %>%
    distinct(new, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
    select(-new)
```

Comment: Perfect, this gave the exact row number as running ```uniq``` command in Bash

Answer (score 2):

From the [R docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/unique):

> Note that unlike the Unix command `uniq` this omits duplicated and not just repeated elements/rows. That is, an element is omitted if it is equal to any previous element and not just if it is equal the immediately previous one. (For the latter, see `rle`).